# Adding an object to an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to add a new Entry object to an array of objects. I don't know how I would go about writing a method to do this. Also I'd like to increase the size of the array as new elements are added to it.

```
public class Entry {

    private String surname, initial, extension;

    public Entry() { }

    public Entry(String surname, String initial, String extention) {
        this.surname = surname;
        this.initial = initial;
        this.extension = extention;
    }
}
```

I want to write the method to add the elemets to the array here. The new Entry object is currently hard coded but this will obviously be altered.

```
public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory {

    Entry[] entries = new Entry[4];


    public void addEntry(Entry newEntry) {
        newEntry = new Entry("isajas","ssds", "sasdas");

    }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my question!

Comment: Have you considered using an `ArrayList<Entry>` rather than rolling your own dynamic array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do exactly what you're asking:

```
public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory {
    Entry[] entries = new Entry[1];

    public void addEntry(Entry newEntry) {
        Entry[] temp = new Entry[entries.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = entries[i];
        }
        newEntry = new Entry("isajas","ssds", "sasdas");
        temp[temp.length - 1] = newEntry;
        entries = temp;
      }
}
```

But as many suggested, ArrayList (or even Vector) would be a better choice than trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [java.util.ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead. It is a "resizable-array implementation of the *List* interface" and provides an easy-to-use API for adding objects, e.g. `ArrayList<Type>().add(Object o)`. Have a look at the Javadoc link above, it's really handy and I use it a lot.

It also saves you the extra work of assigning temporary arrays to-and-fro and creating extra objects...

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a variable which tells you the number of Entries present in the directory.
Every time you add/remove an entry just update this variable. Effectively you are implementing a `Stack`.

```
public class ArrayDirectory implements Directory {

  Entry[] entries = new Entry[4];
  private int numEntries = 0;

  public void addEntry(Entry newEntry) {
    if (numEntries == 4) { /* Display an error */ }

    newEntry = new Entry("isajas","ssds", "sasdas");
    entries[numEntries] = newEntry;
    numEntries++;
  }
}
```

Or alternatively you can java's inbuilt ArrayList data structure to add/remove entries.